# size tbl data 'explodes' after gather()

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a file that I want to convert from wide to long format.
but when I use the gather() function the size increases a lot.
the dataset starts with the size of **332MB** (1048498 obs. of 64 variables)
after 1 gather() the size is 3GB, and after a second it is **32.3 GB**  (177196162 obs. of 42 variables)

does anyone know if this is normal behavior?

edit: example

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

nycflightData <- dplyr::full_join(planes, flights, by = "tailnum")
nycflightDataLonger <- gather(testData, planeVar, planeInfo, tailnum,
                              type, manufacturer, model, engine,
                              engines, seats, convert = TRUE)
```

this dataset goes from 49MB to 270MB

Comment: Can you whip up an example that demonstrates this?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I just realize that it does make sense, as when going from wide to long the number of original observations get added for each column (exept the 1st)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realize that it does make sense, as when going from wide to long the number of original observations get added for each column (exept the 1st)